# Using Rasa NLU model with python API instead of HTTP server

Tags: python, rasa-nlu

Is there a way to use https://nlu.rasa.com model without the HTTP server ? I want to use it as a python library/module.

Comment: I think you can do that with the [excerpt](https://nlu.rasa.com/python.html#training-time) from here.

Comment: yes, found the page right after I posted the question

Comment: but in most cases you would need a REST api to fetch the payload or train it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, and this is documented in there docs at nlu.rasa.com specifically [this section](https://nlu.rasa.com/python.html).

As of version 0.12.3:

**Training**

```
from rasa_nlu.training_data import load_data
from rasa_nlu.config import RasaNLUModelConfig
from rasa_nlu.model import Trainer
from rasa_nlu import config

training_data = load_data('data/examples/rasa/demo-rasa.json')
trainer = Trainer(config.load("sample_configs/config_spacy.yml"))
trainer.train(training_data)
model_directory = trainer.persist('./projects/default/')  # Returns the directory the model is stored in
```

**Parsing**

```
from rasa_nlu.model import Metadata, Interpreter

# where `model_directory points to the folder the model is persisted in
interpreter = Interpreter.load(model_directory)

interpreter.parse(u"The text I want to understand")
```